# Class operator overload

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have a problem with return type of my class operator overload.
I want to return the same object when operator does it's thing so i can continue the sequence.
I have a class Console and this code:

```
template <class out>
Console& Console::operator<<(const out &data)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << data;
    output += ss.str();
    return this;
}
```

but the error I get is

> UI_Console.cpp: In member function 'vui::Console&
> vui::Console::operator<<(const out&)': UI_Console.cpp:13:12: error:
> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'vui::Console&'
> from an rvalue of type 'vui::Console*'

I can make it void but when I call an operator on object like:

```
Console obj;
obj << "Hello" << "World\n";
```

I get an error that the second operator doesn't know what to do. How can I make it work?

Comment: `return *this;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return `this` as a pointer. Your function declaration requires a reference, thus you need `return *this;`.

Comment: I tried, but get undefined reference error.'undefined reference to `vui::Console& vui::Console::operator<< <char [16]>(char const (&) [16])'' when I try using the operator. I declare Console object like ' Console obj; and then use obj << "something"; ' and get that error.

Comment: @VukMar This is a different error. Likely you have the function in the cpp and not in the header (and haven't manually instantiated the template for the type(s) you use it).

Comment: I have 4 files that I work with, console.cpp, console.hpp, main.cpp, main.hpp, everything is included the right way. console.cpp includes console.hpp and main.hpp includes console.hpp and all the declarations needed and main.cpp includes main.hpp. everything is used in main.cpp. every aspect of the class console is working except the operator<<. when I make it void with no return type it works but only for the first operation. so then I use `obj << "asdasd" << "asdad";` compiler doesn't know what to do. the `<<` operator doesn't match const char[] and const char[].

Comment: I made it work. You were right the definition of `operator<<` was in **console.cpp** and that was the problem. Thanks for your time!